# How can I make aperture function (telescope's aperture) in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Can anyone help me to make aperture function in Matlab? I tried by making a matrix, but it wasn't helpful.

Comment: You could just take a black piece of paper and cut a circular hole in it, and glue it to your telescope :p Or what else do you want to do with your aperture?

Comment: What are you asking for? What is the input data, what is the expected output data?

Comment: thnx a lot for replies.

Comment: I wanna to simulate telescope aperture by some aberrations. So i should make the aperture function, then multiply it by Phase.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the image processing toolbox you can use [`fspecial`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/fspecial.html):

```
A =  fspecial('disk',10);
```

This will create an aperture of radius 10 pixels.
Next, you can embed this matrix in a bigger zero matrix, using `padarray`, for example:

```
A = padarray(A,[20 20]);
```

Comment: +1: good answer to a poor question, kudos to you!

Comment: thanks! receiving this from someone like you is a big compliment!